# Implicit meaning of お前にも and 自分にも

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

In a manga, a character thinks about the feelings he has about his opponent (Jin) before a fight:

> いつもいらついてる
>
> むかつく　歯痒い　‥‥‥悔しい
>
> 仁【じん】、お前にも
>
> 自分にも
>
> だから

And then the two characters start to fight. What I don't understand is the meaning of お前にも and 自分にも. I think there is something unsaid here, but I am not sure what it is. Could it be "both you and me know that (the fact I can't stand you)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least from the context provided, there seems to be nothing left unsaid or implied.  It is all written out there.

「いつもいらついている」("I am always irritated")

↓

「仁{じん}、お前{まえ}**にも**」 = "by/towards you, Jin"

↓

「自分{じぶん}**にも**」 = "and by/towards myself as well"

Japanese word order is far more flexible than some might think or even have been taught (***as long as the right particles are used at the right places***).

A more common way of saying the above would be:

> 「（オレは）、仁、お前にも、（また/そして）自分にも、いつもいらついている。」

Finally, I will not go without saying that, by using the inverted word order as in the orignal, the statement sounds much more "dramatic" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is an inversion. It means お前にも自分にも, むかつく, 歯痒い, ‥‥‥悔しい.

Comment: I agree with you answer, but it is more likely to be  「お前にも/自分にも **いらついてる**」, because 「○○に歯痒い」 and 「○○に悔しい」 are unnatural.

Comment: I dither over whether or not to include "いつもいらついてる", of course, it can be included. I feel 「○○にも歯がゆい」 isn't unnatural and it may include them contextually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still don't understand the meaning of お前にも自分にも. Does it mean that they can't stand each other reciprocally?

Comment: It means both you and me, that is to say, "I feel nausea, chagrined and frustrated by you and me."